# Populating Formula field values from Service Cloud to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud

Is there any solution to populate value of  Formula fields ,which are not populating correctly from Service Cloud to Marketing Cloud synchronized  DE?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with formula fields in the context of Marketing Cloud Connect (MCC) is, that these will not update, unless the record containing the formula field also updates. How MCC works, is that only records which are updated are considered for synchronisation, and the fact that a record referenced by the formula field is updated, is not enough.

You can still use formula fields with MCC, but these should just be referencing other fields on the same record. In this case, MCC will see the record as updated, and fetch it along with an updated formula field.

If you really need to use a formula field referencing other objects, you would need a trigger (on the object referenced by the formula) to update the record containing the formula field.